How to add codemirror 6 to tinymce 7 plugins?
Can you give me a straightforward instruction to add codemirror 6 to tinymce 7 without using npm or bundlers, etc. ?
I tried lots of ways but no chance!
It seems that codemirror 6 needs bundling which I don't know, and tinymce 7 has changed plugin registration...
Or any other alternative to codemirror or its native Enhanced Code Editor?
